# extract from line to line to separate file with line number to be a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I tried to extract text from line N to line M in bash to a separate file, with N and M to be variable. 
For example, I want to extract from line 3 to line 5. I set

```
N=3
M=5
```

and do

```
sed -n 'N,Mp' input > output
```

It doesn't work for me.

Comment: You need to reference `M` and `N` as shell variables and double quote the string.which is passed to sed. This would read `sed -n "${M},${N}p" file > output` (be aware that m is alphabetically before n, this has nothing to do with your answer or question, but just a generic remark that you might want to swap the values assigned to m and n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with sample `awk` script:

```
awk -v s=$N -v n=$M 'NR>s && NR<n' input >output
```

with `sed` will be something like:

```
sed -n "${N},${M}p" input >output
```